# Gtest : Linking error in google-test sample using arm platform in linux

Tags: c++, linux, gradle, arm, googletest

I just want to move from CMake to Gradle build system.
So, I have successfully build my project in gradle.

Now, I want to move all test that are writen in cxxTest framwork to GoogleTest framwork.

I am newbie in gtest. So I just download sample [google-test](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/google-test) and build it. And its run as expected.

Now, the `lobgtest.a` is build with `x86` plateform, And I want to run in arm plateform.

So, I have download [gtest source](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/checkout) code from svn and build with `arm toolchain`.

`svn checkout http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ googletest-read-only`

Now, If I run the same sample google-test with arm `libgtest.a` and its give me linking error as below.

```
build@project-build:~/google-test$ gradle build
:compileFailingOperatorsSharedLibraryOperatorsCpp
:linkFailingOperatorsSharedLibrary
:failingOperatorsSharedLibrary
:compileFailingOperatorsStaticLibraryOperatorsCpp
:createFailingOperatorsStaticLibrary
:failingOperatorsStaticLibrary
:compileFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExeOperatorsCpp
:compileFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExeOperatorsTestCpp
:linkFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExe
/home/build/google-test/build/objs/operatorsTestGoogleTestExe/failing/operatorsTestCpp/amp5iswcui5p9bl2w9yf2xmbg/test_plus.o
: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test_plus.cpp:(.text+0x4b8): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, void const*, void (*
)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
/home/build/google-test/build/objs/operatorsTestGoogleTestExe/failing/operatorsTestCpp/2potarenow2sn212d22q3bhj9/test_minus.
o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test_minus.cpp:(.text+0x4b8): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, void const*, void (
*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

:linkFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExe FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':linkFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExe'.
> A build operation failed.
      Linker failed while linking operatorsTest.
  See the complete log at: file:///home/build/google-test/build/tmp/linkFailingOperatorsTestGoogleTestExe/output.txt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.365 secs
```

Here is my modified build.gradle file for arm plateform.

```
model {
....
    toolChains {
      gcc(Gcc) {
        target('arm') {
          // this is more portable if the path is provided by the environment
          path "/usr/local/compilers/arm-cs-tools/bin"
          cCompiler.executable 'arm-my-linux-gnueabi-g++'
          cppCompiler.executable 'arm-my-linux-gnueabi-g++'
          linker.executable 'arm-my-linux-gnueabi-g++'
          assembler.executable 'arm-my-linux-gnueabi-as'
          staticLibArchiver.executable 'arm-my-linux-gnueabi-ar'
        }
      }
    }
    platforms {
        arm {
            architecture 'arm'
        }
    }
    components {
        operators(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            // targetPlatform "x86"
            targetPlatform 'arm'
        }
    }
.....
}
```

Can you please suggest me some way to run gtest in arm platform.

OS : `Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)`

Many thanks.